# Always automatic log in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there a way to force an automatic log in WiX?

Currently, to generate a log I need to execute my package using this parameter:

```
application.msi /l*v log.txt
```

I would like to find a way in the `<Product>` tag - for example - to force the log to be always enabled. I know this is possible in [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MsiLogging property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370322.aspx) is your solution here. According to the documentation:

> The MsiLogging property sets the default logging mode for the Windows
>   Installer package. If this optional property is present in the
>   Property table, the installer generates a log file named MSI*.LOG. The
>   full path to the log file is given by the value of the
>   MsiLogFileLocation property.

Comment: One bit of caution.  There is a known defect in Windows 7 that sometimes Explorer has a memory (Heap) problem that causes it to forget where the TEMP diretory is. Then when you try to uninstall an MSI with this property set  it fails to write to the log and the installer fails with an error.  I fielded several help desk tickets over this issue and it was enough for me to decide to not use this feature.

Comment: No problem!  It's one of those been there done that things... :)

Comment: Yes, the `MsiLogging` property should work, but when I set the `MsiLogFileLocation` to the desired value, it gets overwritten during execution.

Comment: I discovered that is not possible to set `MsiLogFileLocation` from the WiX package. So the only solution for specifying the log file location is to use a bootstrapper.